# Count number of terms of individual take the leaderboard

Tags: excel, if-statement, countif

I'm searching a solution that can be accomplished use the basic function provided by Excel/Google sheet **(without touching vba)**.

The problem is this, I'm building some sort of record of a leaderboard.

- Given the column A recording who is the leader X in that week.
- I want
  some naive formula in column B able to tell me this the n-th term of
  X as leader
- Column C will have formula counting this is the m-th week
  in X's current term.

[image]

This is a MWE in Google Sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XiUYTBupz5V-4xb7AoN73kzIKQA00k4W2oUMfoZcHRI/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try for `Term`:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2,$A$1:A1,"<>"&A2)
```

and for `Week`:

```
=if(A2<>A1,1,C1+1)
```

both formulas works in GS and Excel. Should be copied down.

[image]

---

Explanation for `B10` - the function performs the calculation in two parts:

1. `$A$2:A10=A10` is converted to `{A,A,A,B,B,C,A,A,A}=A` and returns an boolean array `{T,T,T,F,F,F,T,T,T}`
2. `$A$1:A9<>A10` is converted to `{Given,A,A,A,B,B,C,A,A}<>A` and returns an boolean array `{T,F,F,F,T,T,T,F,F}`
3. both arrays are combined with the `AND` operator which returns array `{T,F,F,F,F,F,T,F,F}`
4. from which `COUNTIFS` counts `2`

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution. I'm more interested in the logic behind the countifs formula. For example, Cell B10 reads "=COUNTIFS($A$2:A10,A10,$A$1:A9,"<>"&A10)". May I ask in this case, how the countifs works, say in Cell B10?

Comment: I see, you actually offset the the second condition by 1 to count the transition of term. Very elegant solution indeed. :-)